# Display Joomla component within a module

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to display a Joomla 2.5 component in a module.
In my module entrypoint I have:

```
JLoader::import('joomla.application.component.model');
JLoader::import( 'quizzes', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_questions/models' );
JLoader::import('joomla.application.component.controller');

if (!class_exists('QuestionsControllerQuizzes')) {
    require_once (JPATH_SITE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_questions/controllers' . DS . 'quizzes.php');
}

$quiz_controller = new QuestionsControllerQuizzes(false, $params->get('poll'));

$quiz_controller->execute( JRequest::getVar('task','load') );
```

I tried to debug it and it seems that can't load the correct view. Seems to looking for a generic com_content in $this->basePath.

The strange thing is that if I load the module in a page where the component is loaded, it display correctly.

Any idea how to succesfully display the component output in a module?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [How to display Joomla component in a module](http://www.bzzzz.biz/blog/joomla/how-to-display-joomla-component-in-a-module.bzzzz)

and remember your controller should include a function for the task!

Comment: here is another one with a interesting comment at the end:http://www.escope.cz/en/blog/94-how-to-load-component-in-a-module

Comment: Hi Trajo. I've seen also that one. I guess I'm missing something then. When i try to override properties, it returns : Call to a member function setProperties() on null...

Comment: At minimum you need to change JRequest to JInput.